# "Wizard of Oz" in NaOqi Robot

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone has ever programmed their NAOqi robot in a way that when you press one button on your keyboard such as 'A' the robot will say a certain dialogue. Like in the movie "The Wizard of Oz" how the man behind the curtain puppeteer the hologram with buttons and controls instead of the hologram being programmed to talk by itself through voice commands already. I  want to be the man behind the curtain and to control my robot with a button and for it to say something through my actions, not the robot to respond to any voice commands. Thank you.

Comment: Funny thought..but not material as such to post on SO. Did you check the sister sites or a forum? If you have a script to share where you try to accomplish this but fail..then this is the forum for you!!

Comment: I am very knew to this programming but, where are these other sister forums you speak of? Thank you.

Comment: There are [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Or located next to the "?" top-right on your SO page. If you finish the SO tour you'll get a grasp of what more advantages SO has in stock.